# Ambiguous Behaviour of RxJava flatMap Operator

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String LOG_TAG = "MY_LOG";
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        compositeDisposable.add(getObservable().subscribeWith(getObserver()));
    }

    private Observable<Integer> getObservable(){
        return Observable.just(1,2,3).flatMap(lValue -> Observable.just(lValue,lValue,lValue));
    }

    private DisposableObserver<Integer> getObserver(){
        return new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Integer s) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onNext : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onError");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onComplete");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The Output of above code is :

```
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 1
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 1
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 2
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 2
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 3
D/MY_LOG: onNext : 3
D/MY_LOG: onComplete
```

Here 1, 2 and 3 are printed twice each time. The expected behavior should be 1, 2, and 3 being printed thrice each time as three values have been passed inside `just` operator inside `flatMap` operator. Does anyone know why this weird behavior is observed?

Comment: (Kotlin) This works as expected: `Observable.just(1, 2, 3).flatMap { Observable.just(it, it, it) }.subscribe { println(it) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code seems to be fine. It could be an issue with the Log also sometimes that, the log may not print all the values if you are frequently printing.
Try adding a `doOnNext` and see if the `just` emits all the values

```
 Observable.just(lValue,lValue,lValue).doOnNext(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer integer) throws Throwable {
            Log.d(TAG, "accept: "+ integer);
            // or use debugger to check the value
        }
    })
```